# Serial line hangs after first call

Tags: gpio, serial, c, uart

I have written a short program to monitor a serial line using the uart on GPIO-Pin 8/10.
It works fine the first time I start the program, but hangs without any output the 2nd time I call it. To be more specific, it hangs at the "open" call. Is the line not propperly closed?
How to reset the line or whatever to do to connect again?

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <stdlib.h>     // exit()
#include <termios.h>    // struct termios
#include <fcntl.h>      // O_RDWR

#define DEVICE "/dev/ttyAMA0"

int main()
{
        struct termios port_param;
        int port_fd;

        port_fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
        if (port_fd < 0) {perror(DEVICE); exit(-1);}

        port_param.c_cflag      = B9600 | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CREAD;
        port_param.c_cflag      |= PARENB | PARODD;     // ODD Parity
        port_param.c_iflag      = INPCK | PARMRK;       // Mark wrong parity
        port_param.c_iflag      &= ~IGNPAR;             // Don't ignore parity
        port_param.c_oflag      = 0;
        port_param.c_lflag      = 0;
        port_param.c_cc[VTIME]  = 1;
        port_param.c_cc[VMIN]   = 1;

        cfsetospeed(&port_param, B9600);
        cfsetispeed(&port_param, B9600);
        tcsetattr(port_fd, 0, &port_param);

        int c;
        for (c=0; c<10; c++)
        {
                char    cbuf[30];
                int     ibuf[10];
                int     noc = read(port_fd, cbuf, 9);
                int     noi;
                int     i;
                for (i = 0;i < noc; i++)
                        printf("%02x ", cbuf[i]);
                printf(" -- %d\n", noc);
        }
        close(port_fd);
}
```

Comment: After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328540/open-blocks-trying-to-open-a-serial-port I started minicom. minicom works fine and prints the received chars, but my program would still not open the line.

Comment: O_NONBLOCK solves the blocking, but then read usually returns -1. Ok, that will do it for now, still I would appreciate to recive usefull insights.